# Realm Java. Not upload data from local Realm to remote Ream Object server

Tags: java, realm

I want to create Android db by Realm and sync it.

Here my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

realm {
    syncEnabled = true;
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.realm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            configBuildType(delegate, "\"http://162.117.212.243:8080\"", "\"default\"", "\"myaccount_on_server@mycom.com\"", "\"my_pass\"")
        }
    }
}

def configBuildType(buildType, authURL, realmName, userName, password) {
    println("configBuildType: buildType.name = " + buildType.name + ", authURL = " + authURL
            + ", userName = " + userName + ", password = " + password)
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", "AUTH_URL", authURL)
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", "REALM_NAME", realmName)
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", "USER_NAME", userName)
    buildType.buildConfigField("String", "PASSWORD", password)
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

So here my code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
private static final String TAG = MyApplication.class.getName();
private static SyncConfiguration synConfiguration;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate:");

    Realm.init(this);
    RealmLog.setLevel(Log.VERBOSE);


    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String authURL = BuildConfig.AUTH_URL;
                SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword(BuildConfig.USER_NAME, BuildConfig.PASSWORD, false);
                SyncUser user = SyncUser.login(syncCredentials, authURL);
                String realmURL = BuildConfig.AUTH_URL + "/~/" + BuildConfig.REALM_NAME;
                synConfiguration = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, realmURL)
                        //.waitForInitialRemoteData()
                        //.readOnly()
                        .build();
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: run: SUCCESS synConfiguration:\n\n" + synConfiguration + "\n\n");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: run: error = " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

public static SyncConfiguration getSynConfiguration() {
    return synConfiguration;
}
```

}

After start my android app on it's success login and as result on logcat I get next text:

```
  onCreate: run: SUCCESS synConfiguration:

 realmDirectory: /data/data/com.realm/files/realm-object-server/1d4e1a03e382046ea9bf7cfacc9a4ece/1d4e1a03e382046ea9bf7cfacc9a4ece
 realmFileName : default
 canonicalPath: /data/data/com.realm/files/realm-object-server/1d4e1a03e382046ea9bf7cfacc9a4ece/1d4e1a03e382046ea9bf7cfacc9a4ece/default
 key: [length: 0]
 schemaVersion: 0
 migration: null
 deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
 durability: FULL
 schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@4222c508
 readOnly: false
 compactOnLaunch: null
 serverUrl: realm://162.117.212.243:8080/1d4e1a03e382046ea9bf7cfacc9a4ece/default
 user: {UserId: 1d4e1a03e382046ea9bf7cfacc9a4ece, AuthUrl: http://162.117.212.243:8080/auth, IsValid: true, Sessions: 0}
 errorHandler: io.realm.SyncManager$1@42230f78
 deleteRealmOnLogout: false
 waitForInitialRemoteData: false
```

OK!

So now I want to add some data to db. Here code:

```
 public static void addOrUpdateOrganisation(final String organisationASJson) {
        Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(MyApplication.getSynConfiguration());
        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.createOrUpdateObjectFromJson(Organisation.class, organisationASJson);
                }
            });
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }
    }



public class Organisation extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    @Required
    private String name;
    private String address;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nOrganisation{" +
                "id = " + id +
                ", name = '" + name + '\'' +
                ", address = '" + address + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

New ogranisation success add to local Realm. But on Realm Object Server data(new organisation) is not show.
Why?

Here logcat with Realm log:

```
E/com.realm.server.server.AndroidWebServer( 3277): serve: 
D/com.realm.server.server.AndroidWebServer( 3277): serve:
D/com.realm.server.server.AndroidWebServer( 3277): serve: Add/update organization...
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_RealmFileUserStore_nativeGetCurrentUser
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_RealmFileUserStore_nativeIsActive
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_RealmFileUserStore_nativeIsActive
E/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277): addOrUpdateOrganisation: current user = {UserId: fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c, AuthUrl: http://162.117.212.243:9080/auth, IsValid: true, Sessions: 0}
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_RealmFileUserStore_nativeIsActive
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCreateConfig
D/REALM_JAVA( 3277): first session created add network listener
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetSharedRealm 1473371832
D/REALM_JNI( 3277): Callback to Java requesting token for path
D/REALM_JAVA( 3277): Scheduling an access_token refresh in 280076 milliseconds
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeSetAutoRefresh 1472689096
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCloseConfig 1473371832
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeHasTable 1472689096
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetTable 1472689096
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCloseSharedRealm 1472689096
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_RealmFileUserStore_nativeIsActive
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCreateConfig
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetSharedRealm 1473400008
D/REALM_JNI( 3277): Callback to Java requesting token for path
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetVersion 1472884688
I/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Opening Realm file: /data/data/com.realm.server/files/realm-object-server/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/sg
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: WebSocket::Websocket()
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Reconnecting in 0 milliseconds
I/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Session[12]: Starting session for '/data/data/com.realm.server/files/realm-object-server/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/sg'
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Session[12]: last_version_available  = 8
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Session[12]: progress_server_version = 0
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Session[12]: progress_client_version = 0
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Using already open Realm file: /data/data/com.realm.server/files/realm-object-server/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/sg
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Session[12]: Progress handler called, downloaded = 0, downloadable = 0, uploaded = 0, uploadable = 258, progress version = 0, snapshot version = 8
I/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Resolving '162.117.212.243:9080'
I/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Connecting to endpoint '162.117.212.243:9080' (1/1)
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeSetAutoRefresh 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCloseConfig 1473400008
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetVersion 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeBeginTransaction 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetVersion 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetVersion 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_OsSchemaInfo_nativeCreateFromList
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeUpdateSchema 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeHasTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeHasTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_UncheckedRow_nativeGetString 1472887608
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCommitTransaction 1472884688
I/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Connected to endpoint '162.117.212.243:9080' (from '172.27.202.74:39542')
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: WebSocket::initiate_client_handshake()
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeBeginTransaction 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetVersion 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeHasTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeGetTable 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_UncheckedRow_nativeGetString 1472888688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsInTransaction 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_UncheckedRow_nativeGetIndex 1473409440
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_UncheckedRow_nativeSetString 1473409440
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsInTransaction 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_UncheckedRow_nativeGetIndex 1473409440
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_UncheckedRow_nativeSetString 1473409440
D/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277): executeTransaction: execute: SUCCESS created/updated organisation:
D/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277): {
D/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277):   "id": 1,
D/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277):   "address": "Address 1",
D/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277):   "name": "Ogranisation 1"
D/com.realm.server.service.OrganisationService( 3277): }
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: HTTP request =
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): GET /realm-object-server HTTP/1.1
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection: Upgrade
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Host: 162.117.212.243
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Sec-WebSocket-Key: 3wrQNa93e9Cs6MyN+meAVQ==
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: io.realm.protocol
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Upgrade: websocket
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): X-Realm-Access-Token: eyJhY2Nlc3MiOlsiZG93bmxvYWQiLCJ1cGxvYWQiLCJtYW5hZ2UiXSwiYXBwX2lkIjoibWQucmVhbG0uc2VydmVyIiwiZXhwaXJlcyI6MTUwMjE4NDQ3MCwiaWQiOiJkMTQ1YjM0NmJkMjM0N2M3OTFhNGVhMTIxNDBlY2M4OSIsImlkZW50aXR5IjoiZmNjYzQ2YmJlMjM1NGJhZTM1ZDNkZGI5ZTgyODcwMGMiLCJwYXRoIjoiL2ZjY2M0NmJiZTIzNTRiYWUzNWQzZGRiOWU4Mjg3MDBjL3NnIn0=:OdHN3vi05miZns6mUPPZIKFE+U0kp6UWRMDgOA6HSRdsI5yRDY8QsOI8fzckNGzN6iZc9dhoLNh4Nwwx520CtID39VVYNIpGrRSGhgKBUqnNAfk7vz0BaU4F3d4nSaOAG80QX9v0PUB0ZbzuoIGFYP2y1hipPTwPYbcir9Rwe/YbI1VKhLSAF2sARdNHUyuaedV/wIzXC51DNAQvDhQ8KcdVUyC2/+7j1nBg2jR1G0IbKxcCbeNE8kcatZYGnZzcxxaMJwyr3MUEdwtVXFRLKZXHaZy4GQXZx4/rd6MGM8+hzMgwOV5P4LUTfApWzAjystHWkFPJ2qnDyvz9BLP3OQ==
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): X-Realm-Path: /fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/sg
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): X-Realm-Protocol-Version: 18
V/REALM_SYNC( 3277): 
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Using already open Realm file: /data/data/com.realm.server/files/realm-object-server/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/sg
D/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Connection[4]: Session[12]: Progress handler called, downloaded = 0, downloadable = 0, uploaded = 0, uploadable = 258, progress version = 0, snapshot version = 9
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeIsClosed 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCommitTransaction 1472884688
V/REALM_JNI( 3277):  --> Java_io_realm_internal_SharedRealm_nativeCloseSharedRealm 1472884688
D/REALM_JAVA( 3277): last session dropped, remove network listener
D/com.realm.server.server.AndroidWebServer( 3277): serve: RESULT RESPONSE:
D/com.realm.server.server.AndroidWebServer( 3277): {Success}
I/REALM_SYNC( 3277): Closing Realm file: /data/data/com.realm.server/files/realm-object-server/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/fccc46bbe2354bae35d3ddb9e828700c/sg
D/dalvikvm( 7361): GC_CONCURRENT freed 388K, 5% free 9124K/9568K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 27ms
```

Comment: I doubt the uploading stops because of all the Realm instances are closed. We have an opened issue for this https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/5028 Would you please try to make the Realm instance (any) lives longer to see if the uploading can be finished?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comments about, syncing only happens while a Realm instance is open, so most likely you have closed the Realm before it could finish uploading all changes.

You can use Sync Progress Notifications to be made aware of when all changes are uploaded. See the section in the docs here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sync-sessions

```
ProgressListener listener = new ProgressListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange(Progress progress) {
        if (progress.isTransferComplete()) {
          // Realm can be safely closed now
          // Remember that this callback happens on a different thread
          // than where the Realm live.
        }
    }
};

SyncSession session = SyncManager.getSession(getSyncConfiguration());
session.addUploadProgressListener(ProgressMode.CURRENT_CHANGES, listener);
```